# ternary operator not working in map function react

Tags: reactjs

I am mapping through an array of objects, some of the images are broken so I created a function to check the image which returns true or false and if false then use a placeholder image.

However I am getting an error and I think its because I am using a ternary operator inside the map function. Any ideas?

Function:

```
public renderProfile() {

// Grabs the array of objects
const profiles = this.state.profiles; 

// Renders the selected profile
const renderProfiles = profiles.splice(0, this.props.postCount).map(profile => (

  this.checkImageUrl(profile.imgUrl) ? profile.imgUrl : profile.imgUrl = 'https://via.placeholder.com/300x167.png?text=LINKEDIN';

  <div key={shortid.generate()} className={styles.linkedInContainer}> 
    <DocumentCard
      aria-label={profile.postContent}
      onClickHref={profile.postUrl}
    > { profile.imgUrl && 
        <img className={styles.linkedInHeroImage } src={ profile.imgUrl } />
      }
      <DocumentCardTitle
        title={profile.postContent}
        shouldTruncate={true}
      />
      <DocumentCardActivity
        activity={`Likes: ${profile.likeCount}`}
        people={[{ name: 'Read more on linkedIn', profileImageSrc: profile.imgUrl ? profile.imgUrl : 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAA' }]}
      />
    </DocumentCard>
  </div>

));
return renderProfiles;
}
```

This is braking it:

```
this.checkImageUrl(profile.imgUrl) ? profile.imgUrl : profile.imgUrl = 'https://via.placeholder.com/300x167.png?text=LINKEDIN';
```

[15:43:22] Error - [tsc] src/webparts/linkedIn/components/LinkedIn.tsx(143,157): error TS1005: ')' expected.
[15:43:22] Error - [tsc] src/webparts/linkedIn/components/LinkedIn.tsx(163,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
[15:43:22] Error - [tsc] src/webparts/linkedIn/components/LinkedIn.tsx(163,6): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

Check image function:

```
  // Checks linkedIn images for broken ones
  private checkImageUrl(url) {
    var lastPart = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
    if (lastPart === "image") {
       return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

https://codepen.io/bkdigital/pen/poojmbo?editors=1011 - This proves the check url function is working

Comment: Can you please update the post with the definition of checkImageUrl

Comment: Done! @joelgullander

Comment: The result of the ternary isn't being assigned to anything. What's it supposed to do?

Comment: Consider checking if `url` exists in your checkImageUrl function above the string manipulation otherwise you will get nullexception if passed in null

Comment: The ternary is checking if these is a valid image url, if not, it gives it a fall back image. (Its updated now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line,

```
const renderProfiles = profiles.splice(0, this.props.postCount).map(profile => (
```

You start the function passed to `.map()` with a `(`.
JavaScript will interpret anything that comes after it as the return value of the function.
Since your function has another statement inside of it, this will cause an error.

You should change it as follow:

```
const renderProfiles = profiles.splice(0, this.props.postCount).map(profile => {
  this.checkImageUrl(profile.imgUrl) ? profile.imgUrl : selectedProfile.imgUrl = 'https://via.placeholder.com/300x167.png?text=LINKEDIN';

  return (
    <div key={shortid.generate()} className={styles.linkedInContainer}> 
      <DocumentCard
        aria-label={profile.postContent}
        onClickHref={profile.postUrl}
      > { profile.imgUrl && 
        <img className={styles.linkedInHeroImage } src={ profile.imgUrl } />
      }
      <DocumentCardTitle
        title={profile.postContent}
        shouldTruncate={true}
      />
      <DocumentCardActivity
        activity={`Likes: ${profile.likeCount}`}
        people={[{ name: 'Read more on linkedIn', profileImageSrc: profile.imgUrl ? profile.imgUrl : 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAA' }]}
      />
    </DocumentCard>
  </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: The ternary still looks nonsensical like this, its value isn't being assigned to anything.

Comment: I know, but it wasn't the question so I refrain from commenting on that part.

Comment: this.checkImageUrl(profile.imgUrl) ? profile.imgUrl : profile.imgUrl = 'https://via.placeholder.com/300x167.png?text=LINKEDIN'; -- Sorry it should of been like this